# How can I print the confusion matrix in the deep learning model?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, metrics, confusion-matrix

```css
def inspection_performance(predicted_fraud, test_fraud):
    
    Inspect_Rate = []
    Precision=[]
    Recall=[]

    
    for i in range(1,100,1):
        
        threshold = np.percentile(predicted_fraud, i)
        precision = np.mean(test_fraud[predicted_fraud > threshold])
        recall = sum(test_fraud[predicted_fraud > threshold])/sum(test_fraud)
        Inspect_Rate.append(100-i)
        Precision.append(precision)
        Recall.append(recall)

    compiled_conf_matrix = pd.DataFrame({
        
        'İnceleme Oranı':Inspect_Rate,
        'Kesinlik':Precision,
        'Hatırlama':Recall,

    })

    return compiled_conf_matrix
```

I can not print the confusion_matrix results. Then I want to get the certainty, recall, and the f-score, but I can't. This is my code guide. How can I get this by writing code similar to the one below?

```
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report, confusion_matrix
print(confusion_matrix(y_test, y_pred))
```

As an example, I want to get results like this at the end.

```
print(classification_report(y_test, y_pred))

                 precision   recall  f1-score   support

           0       0.96      0.68      0.80     37117
           1       0.14      0.67      0.23      2883

    accuracy                           0.68     40000
   macro avg       0.55      0.68      0.52     40000
weighted avg       0.90      0.68      0.76     40000
```

I have to write something else instead of y_test and y_pred. But I don't know how to write.

- For reference, the code of the ROC-AUC curve is as follows. Which tag should be instead of (y_true, y_pred) here?

  ```
   from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
   from sklearn.metrics import roc_curve
   from sklearn.metrics import auc

   fpr, tpr, _ = roc_curve(test_labels.drop(np.where(np.isnan(y_pred))[0]), np.delete(y_pred, np.where(np.isnan(y_pred))[0]))

   plt.plot(fpr, tpr, label='ROC curve')
   plt.plot([0, 1], [0, 1], 'k--', label='Random guess')
   plt.xlabel('False positive rate')
   plt.ylabel('True positive rate')
   plt.title('ROC curve')
   plt.legend(loc="lower right")
   plt.show()
   print('auc: ', auc(fpr, tpr))
  ```
- print(confusion_matrix(?, ?))
- print(classification_report(?, ?))

What should get where there are essentially question marks?

Answer (score 1):

Your question is vague. Do you want the confusion matrix or the classification report?

1. For **confusion matrix**, please refer to this [official documentation of confusion matrix](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.confusion_matrix.html). Here you would do something like this:

```
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
print(confusion_matrix(y_true, y_pred))
```

where,

- y_true: ground_truth labels
- y_pred: predicted labels

Now, in your case there are two parameters of the function: predicted_fraud, test_fraud. Is test_fraud your ground_truth? There must be two labels i.e. either fraud or no fraud (1,0) if yes then,

```
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
print(confusion_matrix(test_fraud.classes, predicted_fraud))
```

2. For the **classification report** please refer to the [official documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.classification_report.html)

```
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report
target_names = ['fraud', 'No fraud']
print(classification_report(test_fraud.classes, predicted_fraud, target_names=target_names))
```

Classification report will give you the main classification metrics of each class (fraud, no fraud) like: precision, recall, f1 score, accuracy etc.

Furthermore, there is a  [github link](https://gist.github.com/RyanAkilos/3808c17f79e77c4117de35aa68447045), it helped me too, hope this helps you as well.

Comment: fpr, tpr, _ = roc_curve(test_labels.drop(np.where(np.isnan(y_pred))[0]),                                         
                                        np.delete(y_pred, np.where(np.isnan(y_pred))[0]))

fpr, tpr were determined in this way to get the ROC-AUC result. I want both the confusion matrix and the classification report. The suggestions below did not work.
print (confusion_matrix (y_true, y_pred))
print (confusion_matrix (test_fraud.classes, projected_fraud))
print (classification_rotation (test_fraud.classes, predicted_ fraud, target_name = target_name))

Comment: @ismail  print (confusion_matrix (y_true, y_pred)) is a general statement. What is test_fraud? Are these ground truth labels? If yes, try this then: print(confusion_matrix(test_fraud, predicted_fraud))

Comment: I could not understand how to encode (y_true, y_pred) predicted values with real values in this model. After calculating the confusion matrix results, I want to get the precision, recall and f score results. I did all the tricks but it didn't work. I don't know the exact reference tags either. The code is as above. What should the tags be here?

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem. The thing that should happen is as follows.

```
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
print(confusion_matrix(test_labels, y_pred.round()))
```